# How to make this matrix like table in the R for the total count?

Tags: r, economics

I want to reproduce the attached table but am not able to do it whatsoever. which package should i use? can anyone redirect me to the right path?

the data look like the following,

```
ID   a     b     c    d
 x   1     0     0    1
 y   0     0     1    1
 z   0     1     1    0
 w   1     1     0    0
```

[image]

Comment: Please revise your question to follow these suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Take a look at `gtsummary` https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is to convert the data you have into a table form that's more aesthetically pleasing, the `flextable` package may be an easy one to use. You can also get the counts of your data by using `adorn_totals` by column and by row. I have tried to recreate your data below and build a table around it:

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(tidyverse) # for piping 
library(flextable) # for table
library(janitor) # for row and column totals

#### Use Same Data ####
ID <- c("x","y","z","w")
a <- c(1,0,0,1)
b <- c(0,0,1,1)
c <- c(0,1,1,0)
d <- c(1,1,0,0)

#### Just Use Adorn Totals ####
df <- data.frame(ID,a,b,c,d) %>% 
  adorn_totals("col") %>% 
  adorn_totals("row")

#### Flextable ####
df %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  add_header_lines("Total by Total Version")
```

Which gives you this:

[image]